# How anyone can access Web app made from google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-deployment

[I deployed script as web app setting anyone can access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qodq.png)

[and get the URL link which ends with /exac.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8g5G.png)

it can access only my account, but others can't.

[when I access with other google accounts,
It can't access and show description:
"Sorry, the file cannot be opened at this time.
Please check the address and try again."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ikbK.png)

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: are you saying the same URL is working with your session, and not working with another?

Answer (score 0):

### It's a new bug

It has already been filed on [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/235862472).

I suggest you to "star" it to increase visibility.

Comment: I don't understand, he's not using getUrl() function. And it's working for him

Comment: @WaximCorp Apparently the bug it is not only related to how one does the URL, but to something being broken at the backend. While I personally cannot reproduce the problem, there have been a lot of people complaining about the same since yesterday.